# SharePoint 2007: How to track time taken of column value changes?

Tags: document-library, site-column, choice-field

I'm working in SharePoint 2007 Document Library, where there is a Choice column named Status, with a value of Assigned, In Progress, Closed.

I wanted to capture the time taken of document status change.

for example:

time taken to change from **Assigned** to **In Progress**

time taken to change from **In Progress** to **Closed**

workaround I can think of at this moment is either using **SharePoint Designer workflow** or **Event Handler** to trigger the item created event and item modified event, then stored the item into a Custom List and calculate the time different.

any better approach to implement the requirement above?

thank you in advanced :)

Answer (score 2):

If you must avoid creating WFs or event handlers, then another option is to use a Calculated field with bunch of new columns (AssignedOn, TimeToInProgress, etc.).

For the first duration:

> time taken to change from **Assigned** to **In Progress**

The first time the user changes the status of the document to Assigned set the AssignedOn column to current date and time.

If the AssignedOn column has a value and the status is now changed to In Progress set the TimeToInProgress = Current datetime - AssignedOn

You get the idea. You can do the second duration similarly.

This site gives you more info about [Calculated Field Formulas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071%28office.12%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution is to Enable versioning and it will give some level of delta.